# PHP Path to user directories

Tags: php, path

Is there a way to find out the path of a user directory in php?

In MAC OS X I can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to find out the path where the documents are
being retrieved. This path is:

```
/Users/jmlopez/www
```

on my computer because I modified my `httpd.conf` file. I believe it was set to `/Library/WebServer/Documents`. In the server at my university it is set to:

```
/home/www/html
```

If I want to retrieve `doc.html` from a folder called `testFolder` I can simply use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/testFolder/doc.html'`. This works great but I cannot find out how
to refer to documents located in the user pages.

### Mac OS X

The user pages are set to be in:

```
/Users/USERNAME/Sites
```

### Linux Server

The user pages in my university server are in

```
/home/www/users/USERNAME/www
```

Is there a way to get this path in php or do I have to analyze `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`?

### My Current Solution

My current solution to obtain the `$fileRoot`

```
$temp = explode("/", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); 
if ( $temp[1] == "home" ) { //Linux
    if ( $temp[3] == "users") { $fileRoot = '/home/www/users/'.$temp[4].'/www';} 
    else { $fileRoot = '/home/www/html/'.$temp[4];} 
} elseif ($temp[1] == "Users" ) { //Mac
    if ( $temp[3] == "www" ) { $fileRoot = '/Users/'.$temp[2].'/www/'.$temp[4]; }
    else { $fileRoot = '/Users/'.$temp[2].'/Sites'; }
}
```

In this way if I'm working on a site, say `http://localhost/someSite`

then `$fileRoot` will point to:

```
/home/www/html/someSite
```

in Linux.

```
/Users/jmlopez/www/someSite
```

in my mac.

Notice that `$fileRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/someSite'` works in both Mac and Linux.

If I'm working on my personal website say `http://localhost/~jmlopez`

then `$fileRoot` will point to:

```
/home/www/users/jmlopez/www
```

in Linux.

```
/Users/jmlopez/Sites
```

in my mac.

The question again is: Is there some way of obtaining this path without using the solution I have posted? Hopefully something simple.

Comment: @icktoofay, there are a set of variables and functions that I like to keep on `/Users/jmlopez/Sites/phprc.php` (in my mac) or `/home/www/users/jmlopez/www/phprc.php` (in linux). What I want to do from any `index.php` is include that file I just mentioned.

Comment: If my site was simply `http://localhost/jmlopez` then I could just do `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/jmlopez/phprc.php');` from any index.php file to obtain my variables and other functions. But I'm a user and my files are located somewhere else.

Comment: You can store the base folder in your index.php using `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache 2.3.13 (also in 2.4.3) has a new feature that may be exactly what you need. I only read about it yesterday but have no had time to try it out. Obviously you'd need a very up-to-date apache as it's only been out a few weeks.

A new evnvironment variable is "CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT" which gets added to the $_SERVER variables. According to the change control, this will give you exactly what you need as was added for this purpose. Can't see any documentation other than the version control notes on it and [2.4 release notes](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.4)

"Introduce new context_document_root and context_prefix which provide information about non-global URI-to-directory mappings (from e.g. mod_userdir or mod_alias) to scripts." Source: http://marc.info/?l=apache-cvs&m=130928191414740

---

Edit:

If you don;t have a recent version of Apache, then you probably have the best solution (check current file). You can also use

```
__DIR__
```

to get the directory of the file you're currently in too, which may be fractionally easier?

Comment: New feature? This should have been here a long time ago. Anyway, I guess it won't work on my system since I haven't upgraded in a while and I doubt the admins in my university will want to upgrade.

Comment: In which case, you probably have the best solution (check current file). You can also use __DIR__ (see answer - the underscores get messed up in the comments) to get the directory of the file you're currently in too, which may be fractionally easier?